# How to parse pretty JSON in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to parse JSON in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/how-to-parse-json-in-javascript)

If you have JSON formatted like this:

```
{
  "id": 10,
  "user": {
    "email": "example.com"
  }
}
```

What is the standard way of parsing that into a JSON object in JavaScript? The use case is if a user is entering JSON into a textarea, parsing that out.

I started doing this but don't want to go down this road if there's already a robust/standard solution:

```
JSON.parse($('#the-textarea').val().replace(/^\s+/mg, '').replace(/\n/g, '')); // not quite right yet, still not parsable...
```

Comment: `JSON.parse()`? There shouldn't be any need to un-pretty it.

Comment: [`$.parseJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/)?

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to do anything. This non-significant whitespace does not make for invalid JSON and will be ignored by the parser.

Comment: It is not working for me for some reason, it's saying `SyntaxError: Unexpected token`...

Comment: @LancePollard: There's a comma missing after the `10`.

Comment: Sorry, that wasn't the issue, here is the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/eLxgB/1/

Comment: @LancePollard: Those `&nbsp;` entities are *not* valid JSON though (the browser renders them as whitespace when part of HTML, but they mess up JSON). [If you remove them it's all good](http://jsfiddle.net/G6HbG/).

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
var result = jQuery.parseJSON(jQuery('#the-textarea').val());
```

By the way, your example is not valid JSON, it's missing a comma. Here is a valid JSON example:

```
{
  "id": 10,
  "user": {
    "email": "example.com"
  }
}
```

http://jsonlint.com/ is your friend ;)